# ГОСТ для документирования программы?

Tags: документация, гост

Здравствуйте коллеги.
Мне нужно для госпредприятия написать документ под названием "***руководство по эксплуатации***" программы. Программу я уже написал. Руководство по эксплуатации просят написать в соответствии с российскими ГОСТами, которые регламентируют, что нужно и что не нужно там писать. Номера ГОСТов заказчик не знает. Нагуглить мне это тоже не удалось.

**Вопрос:** Каким ГОСТом руководствоваться, чтобы написать "*руководство по экслуатации*" программы?

Comment: ГОСТ Р ИСО 9127-94. Или ГОСТы 19.xxx.

Comment: @Yaant  это всё? Может ещё какой-нибудь ГОСТ? Вы писали уже документацию для госки?

Comment: А Вам мало? :) Не писал, благо для этого есть специальные люди, техписатели.